# Mapping one value to another in a list

Tags: python, list, mapping

In a Python list, how can I map all instances of one value to another value?

For example, suppose I have this list:

```
x = [1, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2]
```

Now, perhaps I want to change all `1`'s to `'a'`, all `2`'s to `'b'`, and all `3`'s to `'c'`, to create another list:

```
y = ['a', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b']
```

How can I do this mapping elegantly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use a dictionary and a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> x = [1, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2]
>>> d = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}
>>> [d[i] for i in x]
['a', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b']
>>>
>>> x = [True, False, True, True, False]
>>> d = {True: 'a', False: 'b'}
>>> [d[i] for i in x]
['a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b']
>>>
```

The dictionary serves as a translation table of what gets converted into what.

Comment: Can I also do the same with boolean values? For example, `d = {True: 'a', False: 'b'}`

Comment: @Karnivaurus Note that the map/transform is merely `f(i) for i in x`, where `f(i) -> d[i]` in the example. The transformation just uses the result of `f(i)` applied to each `i`. Then `f(i)` can be described with the behavior of "return 'a' for 1, 'b' for 2.." which can be implemented in numerous ways, including a dictionary look-up.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative solution is to use the built-in function [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) which applies a function to a list:

```
>>> x = [1, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2]
>>> subs = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}
>>> list(map(subs.get, x)) # list() not needed in Python 2
['a', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b']
```

Here the `dict.get` method was applied to the list `x` and each number was exchanged for its corresponding letter in `subs`.

Answer (score 2):

```
In [255]: x = [1, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2]

In [256]: y = ['a', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b']

In [257]: [dict(zip(x,y))[i] for i in x]
Out[257]: ['a', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b']
```

Comment: If I read the question correctly, `y` is not given, but the *mapping* is.

Comment: @LukasGraf: good point. Perhaps a `dict` would be better, then - like ajcr has suggested